# c# property contains only get,where the value set from App.config

Tags: c#

I have a sample c# application.

In the App.config file there is parameters such as `add key="access" value="abcd"` inside `appSettings` tag and in other class file there is a get property such as
`public string Access { get; }` from where I am getting the value `abcd`.Here there is no set property.But I am getting the value of `access` as `abcd` and its working fine.

My question is, where the value of access in App.config is set in the application.

Comment: Right-click on the Access property in Visual Studio and choose "Find all references". This will tell you where it is used.

Comment: I tried it, but no more reference!!

Answer (score 5):

A readonly property still can be set from within the class that defines the property. And that's what is happening here.

Pseudo code:

```
public class Settings
{
    private string _access;

    public Settings()
    {
        _access = read from config;
    }

    public string Access { get { return _access; } }
}
```

Comment: You are saying that the value will automatically taken from config within the constructor??

Comment: @nabu: The real implementation is a bit more involved and the value might actually be read at the first request, but basically that is what is happening, yes.

Comment: thank you.but how can we understand it is readonly. Is t because of that it only have get property.

Comment: @nabu: The property is readonly because it only has a `get` accessor and no (public) `set` accessor.

Comment: One more doubt the property value , that is Access must match the variable in config file except that it must start in uppercase..right??

Comment: Any way thank you @daniel. My doubt was very basic because, I am new in c#,but familiar with java.

Comment: @nabu: The name of the property is automatically generated by Visual Studio based on the config file. However, there is no magic that links a property with the name of a config property to the value in the config file.

Comment: You are saying that my class with get property is generated automatically.Do we want to even declare the variable in the class and then generate the property method(Because in Java we are doing so).??

Comment: Also I cannot find the location where that class is located.Can you please help me in finding that.??

Comment: @nabu: I don't understand that comment, sorry. Java certainly has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Simply right click on the class name and choose "Go to declaration".

Comment: I did it and can see the class. But I think, only the read only mode(virtual concept) is displayed, and it cannot be located on the project(There is no such class anywhere in the project folder).

Comment: @nabu: That class should be in your project, most likely under the `Properties` folder. And there is no such thing as a "virtual concept". I suggest you read up on the .NET and C# basics before proceeding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37523/discussion-between-nabu-and-daniel-hilgarth)

Comment: @nabu: I am not available for chat. If you have additional questions, please post them as such.